# Regex - multiple matches

Tags: java, regex, match

How to fix this regex in order to get the mentioned outcome ?

regex: `(0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])`

string: `LCR005B"*ADM-CID"9876R579BDFL789ABC#12345A[4D32FC2B12345A|113002065][Vanydata][M1234567890AB][Panydata]`

outcome should be:

1. 005B
2. "*ADM-CID"
3. 9876
4. R579BDF
5. L789ABC
6. #12345A
7. [4D32FC2B12345A|113002065]
8. [Vanydata]
9. [M1234567890AB]
10. [Panydata]

Later edit:

This currently outputs:

1. 005B
2. "*ADM-CID"
3. 9876
4. R579BDF
5. L789ABC
6. #12345A
7. [4D32FC2B12345A|113002065]
8. [Vanydata]

Comment: And what doesn't work, whats the current outcome?

Comment: Are `[]` necessary or output without them will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your regex:

```
(0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})
(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")
(\d{4})
(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)
(L[^#]*)
(#[^\[]*)
(\[[^\[]*)
(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])
```

**You do have only 8 capturing groups**, none is repeated, why do you think this should output 10 groups?

OK, Because of the `(?:M|V|P)` of the last group, it would be able to match the content of the 3 last square brackets, but this group is not repeated, so it will match only the first one.

You have 2 possibilities.

1. Put a quantifier behind the last group

   ```
   (0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])+
   ```

   or

   ```
   (0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*]){3}
   ```

   this will now match the string till the end, but there are still only 8 capturing groups and the content of the last one is now not "[Vanydata]" anymore, its the last match of this group "[Panydata]"
2. Add two more groups to your regex

   ```
   (0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])
   ```

   This does now have 10 capturing groups and the result is as you expected. If the Starting letter of those 3 last groups is always the same for each group you can simplify it to

   ```
   (0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[V(?:[^\[])*])(\[M(?:[^\[])*])(\[P(?:[^\[])*])
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30djf)

**Update**

You can make something optional by adding a question mark after it

```
(0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[[VMP](?:[^\[])*])?(\[[VMP](?:[^\[])*])?(\[[VMP](?:[^\[])*])?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30dkp), hovering over the match shows you the content of the capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks, stema. But I would actually like to avoid both alternatives;

Comment: So, what would you then expect from the solution?

Comment: To provide the last 3 items as 3 groups at once - i.e. no after processing and without having to add the pattern 3 times.

Comment: If you want the last 3 items in 3 groups, you need to define those three groups in your pattern.

Comment: is there a way to allow 0 or 1 instance of each of the last 3 groups and without having their order count ?

Comment: @StackoverSdhfgh I added a solution with three optional groups at the end. See the Regexr link for detailed matching behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seems to be the last `Regex` capture group. `(\[(?:M|V|P)(?:[^\[])*])` doesn't seem to work.

This Regex capture group `\[(\w.*|(M|V|P)\d{10}AB)\]` catches your last 3 bracketed words.

Complete regex: `(0(?:[0-9]|[A-F]){3})(\"\*?(?:SIA-DCS|ADM-CID|NULL)\")(\d{4})(R?(?:[0-9]|[A-F])*)(L[^#]*)(#[^\[]*)(\[[^\[]*)(\[(\w.*|(M|V|P)\d{10}AB)\])`